# (GAMS mcp model) Is it possible to change the end value of sets automatically in a loop when solving a model?

Tags: gams-math

I'm working with a model in GAMS that consists of a system of equations, whose values all depend on a set t (time) that is in the range /0*30/.

So, for now, I'm solving the model based on the end value of the set being 30. However, I'd like to also solve the model for different final values of the set t, so that I also solve it for t /0 * 29/, /0 * 28/, /0 * 27/, all the way to /0 * 2/ for example.

QUESTION: Is it possible to change this final value of the set without having to do so manually (at the start of my code), but instead doing it so that the model solves 'itself' for new end values of the set?

I'll share the main parts of my code below (I don't think it's necessary, but I can also share the full model if that would make it clearer).

```
Sets 
     t time period /0*30/ 

     t0(t) Period t=0 
     ts(t) Simulation periods 
     ts2(t) Simulation periods except t=1
     tn(t) Last period ;

t0(t) = yes$(ord(t) eq 1) ;
ts(t) = yes$(ord(t) gt 1) ;
ts2(t) = yes$(ord(t) gt 1 and ord(t) lt card(t)) ;
tn(t) = yes$(ord(t) eq card(t)) ;


Scalars

Parameters

Variables
    p(t)     Price
    d(t)     Demand
    CumD     Cumulative demand
    m_in(t)  Inflow 
    m_out(t) Outflow 
    M(t)     Size 
    C(t)     Cancellation 
    ;

Equations
     EQ1(t)
     EQ2(t)
     EQ3(t)
     EQ4(t)
     EQ5(t)
     EQ6(t)
     EQ7(t)
     EQ7SUM
     ;

Model MSR_YES /EQ1.m_in, EQ2.m_out, EQ3.C, EQ4.M, EQ5.p, EQ6.B, EQ7.d, EQ7SUM.CumD / ;

Solve MSR_YES using mcp ;
```

So far, I've thought of doing a loop, or including a dynamic set for t, but I'm not sure how I would implement that. If I would try to implement a loop, I think it would look somehow like the following:

SumD(t)        (store the value of CumD for each new loop/solution)

loop(t$(**ord**(t) gt 1),

solve MSR_YES **using** **mcp**;

SumD(t) = CumD.l;

);

I am extremely unsure whether this would do what I'd like it to though.

Answer (score 0):

Using a subset and a loop sounds just fine. So, since you use the set `t` in your model, I would define a new set, e.g. `superT` which consists of all `t`s you can ever have and then make `t` a subset of this, e.g.:

```
Set superT    / 0 * 30 /
    t(superT) / 0 *  1 / ;
```

And then you do a `loop` like this to add another element of `superT` to `t` for each new `solve`:

```
loop(superT$(ord(superT) gt 2),
  t(superT) = yes;
  solve MSR_YES using mcp;
  SumD(t) = CumD.l;
);
```